# Bitbucket pipeline cannot find chromedriver.exe even though it is in the same directory

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, bitbucket-pipelines

I am getting this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver.exe'

However, chromedriver.exe is within the same file directory as bitbucket-pipelines.yml in my repo. This is how I'm using chromedriver.exe:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = Service("chromedriver.exe")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
    driver.maximize_window()
    ....
```

This python file is also within the same directory as chromedriver.exe and bitbucket-pipelines.yml. What am I doing wrong?

Edit
bitbucket-pipeline.yml

```
- step:
        name: Get latest versions of libraries
        image: python:3.8.2
        script:
          - pip install selenium
          - pip install beautifulsoup4
          - pip install lxml
          - pip install webdriver-manager
          - python webscrape.py
        artifacts:
          - latest_vers.json
```

Comment: Can you share your bitbucket pipelines yml?

Comment: Hey thanks for replying, shared!

Comment: Thank you, I'm assuming you posted some part of `webscrape.py` right? In this step you are trying to reach `chromedriver.exe` and it keeps failing, right? If there is another pattern you are trying to use, pls clarify.

Comment: Yep, the python code above is from ```webscrape.py``` and it fails in reaching ```chromedriver.exe``` even though all 3 files are in the same directory

Comment: It looks a full path/relative path situation to me right off the bat. Can you try to use `Service("./chromedriver.exe")` or If it doesn't work, `Service("/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/chromedriver.exe")` just to understand.

Comment: I've tried both suggestions, now it gives a new error: PermissionError:
[Errno 13] Permission denied: './chromedriver.exe', 
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/chromedriver.exe'

Comment: Interesting, are you trying to run python script as a different user or something? Because generally speaking, each step is cloning the repo for itself, so it should work. Maybe we can run `ls -la` command in step to see the structure under pipeline directory.

Comment: Nope, not running as a different user. [screenshot of `ls -la`](https://imgur.com/a/J6gxvfR)

Comment: This directory setup is running on your local right? Maybe we can try to reproduce the problem by pulling the pipe image to the local, run the image, get into it, pull the repo and run these commands. At this point I don't think it's related with bitbucket pipelines directly. I mean, it shouldn't be. Last thing comes to my mind that it's not executable in terms of permissions, also pipe image `python:3.8.2` is a linux-based environment and we are trying to run `.exe` file. Other than that, I couldn't think of anything. Creating the same setup in your local might help you to understand